# From array to object (with values) - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to turn an array to an object, and to assign "true" to each value, in JS.

From

`['lastName', 'firstName', 'email']`

to

`{lastName: true, firstName: true, email: true}`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you attempt anything? JS 101 is for loop, Another way is `reduce()`. Modern day approach would be use a Set

Comment: i dont think theres a native js function for this, just iterate the array and assign properties to an object

Answer (score 1):

Seems a good case for `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const keys = ['lastName', 'firstName', 'email'];
const result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, true]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Short and clean!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like that

```
const array = ['lastName', 'firstName', 'email']
const object = {}
array.forEach((e) => object[e] = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array and assign `true` to the values, using them as keys:

```
let myObject = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    let key = myArray[i];
    myObject[key] = true;
}
return myObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reduce() properties [Read Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), ex:

```js
const a = ['lastName', 'firstName', 'email']

const b = a.reduce((prev, current) => ({ ...prev, [current]: true}), {}) 

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const obj = {}
const arr = ['lastName', 'firstName', 'email']
    
arr.forEach(function(el){
    obj[el] = true
})
```